# How to give every item in string-array specific color and show them in spinner?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to make every item in String-array have a different color and I want to show them in spinner:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/alldata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/alldata"
        android:gravity="center"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and this is the string-array                                                                                                       <string-array name="alldata">
        <item>Furniture</item>
        <item>Appliance</item>
        <item>School Tools</item>
    </string-array>

Answer (score 0):

use this to show specific color on spinner

```
  //StringArray
 <string-array name="payment_list">
  <item><![CDATA[<font color="#ff8519">alldata</font>]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[<font color="#85ff94">Furniture</font>]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[<font color="#fff123">Appliance</font>]]></item>
  <item><![CDATA[<font color="#fff123">School Tools</font>]]></item>
</string-array>
```

Activity/Fragment

```
    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.transaction_spinner);
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.payment_list);
    Spanned[] spannedStrings = new Spanned[3];
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        spannedStrings[i] = Html.fromHtml(array[i]);
    }
    spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(MainActivity.this, 
    R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spannedStrings));
```

Comment: give me this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Comment: Spanned[] spannedStrings = new Spanned[3]; change the number 3 instaed of 4 mean number of your stringArray